# Switch Focus without closing dialog in Android

Tags: android

Hi In Android is it possible to switch focus back and forth between an open dialog box and the main view without closing the dialog box. The preferred method of switching would be to click on the unfocused view so that it obtains focus.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the user close the dialog box, and when the user reopens the dialog box, reinitialize the dialog box with the previous value? I think that would be simpler and more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!   Basically I have a text and in the dialog box I have a question about the text I want the user to be able to scroll through the text in order to answer the question about the text.  So I'd prefer the dialog box to remain visible throughout.  I guess using a dialog box is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Engmex: How about a dialog box with a scrollable TextView?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, really old. But I found this wile looking for answer to the same question. I figured out the solution though

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

This can also be done with the same result creating a window through the WindowManager, but the you get more for free using a dialog.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
wm.addView(myView, params);
```